# IE 8 not showing .aspx files?

Tags: c#, vb.net, internet-explorer

I use VB and program in C#.net. I change a file, rebuild my solution, and use IE 8 on my desktop to show my changes. My server uses IIs 7.5. This problem started yesturday mid day. I can open the modified file on the server's IE 8 and it shows the changes. I can use the build in IE in my VB and it shows the changes. However when I try to run it through my IE 8 on the desktop it does not show the changes. I am stumpted...

Comment: Ctrl+F5? Also why do you use IE8? It is outdated since 2010

Comment: I've seen this kind of thing happen if some of the javascript behind the scenes is broken.

Comment: I use IE 8 because of the client I work for... I fixed the javascript and get no errors...

Comment: I had a jquery file that threw an error but I fixed it... is there a way to clear .net cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refresh the page with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or disable IE cache (tools -> internet options -> browsing history -> settings [check "every time i visit the page and set the disk space to 8MB])