# IE 10 not getting latest JS file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-10

I made few changes to a custom js file, which appeared to be updated in Chrome after updating cache but IE 10 just acting like a badass.

I removed cache from IE 10, closed it, deleted all it's history from tools > Internet Options.

It worked in past but now it just doesn't updates it.

I followed all steps in this post but still no good,

http://www.howtogeek.com/127565/how-to-modify-caching-behavior-in-internet-explorer-10/

**Edit**

When I go in Private Browser window, it gets me latest JS file.

**Edit 2**

It fixed itself after steps I performed in Edit 1. ummm strange :/.

Comment: "`I followed all steps in this post but still no good`" So, which alternative you've chosen? If you'll pick the first-one, IE simply doesn't cache anything...

Comment: @Teemu I checked one that requests for new page always and shouldn't get cached version of it.

Comment: Maybe the F12 tools can help. Verify the traffic and maybe you can see why it cached.

Comment: Look my answer on this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408403/ie-8-not-showing-aspx-files/21408490?noredirect=1#comment32295970_21408490

Comment: @bdn02 already tried that, but it didn't worked in my case for unknown reason

Answer (score 2):

If IE10 doesn't understand the cache-mechanism that you want to implement then use time tick to link them in your webpage.

since asp.net is server side langauge. write the code in c# and make a css link like this.

```
<link href="style.css?t=1211" rel="stylesheet" type="Text/css"/>
```

This will fix the cache issue in IE because it's make new call when your css will be updated.

Comment: yes. This method can be applied to both (css and javascript). You can use this on any other resources too (like images,Ajax calls)